# JavaScript - Хранение данных расширения в chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

День добрый.
Сейчас делаю расширение под хром и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: мне нужно сохранить определённые ссылки так, что бы расширение имело к ним доступ после открытия/закрытия окна. В зависимости от количества ссылок на окне расширения должны создаваться контейнеры, внутри которых кнопки, ведущие по этим ссылкам. 
Изначально я использовал local.storage и с этим не было никаких проблем, добавление, удаление и очистка отлично работали, но в последствии оказалось что в расширениях можно использовать только chrome.storage, а у него очень сильно урезан функционал, в том числе отсутствует возможность узнать количество записей в хранилище и адекватно работать с ним у меня не получается.
Подскажите, как я могу решить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать ячейку для счетчика при занесении каждой ссылки, если нужно именно количество, а вообще все ключи можно получить таким образом:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(items) {
var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
console.log(allKeys);
});
```

ну и там уже если нужно обращаться к свойству length.